Prisma "Argument ... is missing"
when trying to create a song, linked to a user i keep getting the error "Argument 'createdBy' missing" despite having set it using various ways.
datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model Song {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  title     String   @db.VarChar(50)
  link      String   @db.VarChar(100)
  artists   Artist[]
  createdBy User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    Int
}

model Artist {
  id        Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name      String @db.VarChar(50)
  songs     Song[]
  createdBy User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    Int
}

model User {
  id       Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name     String   @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  password String   @db.VarChar(255)
  Song     Song[]
  Artist   Artist[]
}

const song = await prisma.song.create({
           data: {
             title: "Testsong",
             link: "aaa",
             artists: {
               create: [
                 {
                   name: "Test1"
                 }
               ]
             },
             userId: 1
             // createdBy: {connect: {id: 1}}
           }
         })

Argument `createdBy` is missing.

I already tried setting it directly with userId as the Prisma Docs say that this is possible in the version I am using. I also tried using connect to connect it to the user through the id.
Did not work.
